# Troca de motivo para fechamento

Tags: debate, bug, status-intencional, filas-de-análise

*[Janela modal com conteúdo do banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32020/janela-modal-com-conte%C3%BAdo-do-banco-de-dados)* é uma duplicata de *https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31812/janela-modal-exibir-conte%C3%BAdo-vindo-do-banco-de-dados-mysql-php*.

Meu 1º voto foi *não é claro o que você está perguntando*. Depois achei a duplicata da questão e retirei meu voto para marcar como duplicata. Aparece o seguinte:

> **Você já votou por encerrar esta pergunta**
>   Você votou por encerrar esta pergunta 5 minutos atrás
>   Você retirou seu voto 3 minutos atrás

É possível trocar o voto ou vai permanecer marcado?

Existe tempo limite para a troca?

---

Uma observação, a questão foi editada e o autor postou o código, agora que deixa de ser uma duplicata da outra questão citada acima. Mas ainda gostaria de saber sobre a troca de voto.

Comment: Não é permitido votar novamente após ter retirado o voto para fechar. Portanto isso é by-design. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193654/how-do-i-change-a-close-vote-to-a-duplicate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction